# app.get() function parameters issue in express

Tags: node.js, express

In the following piece of code "/in/:opt" , what it possibly refers to ?

```
app.get('/in/:opt', function(req, res){
        res.send("Hello");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the route of which express is waiting to match. It will capture the URL

`www.yourdomainORLocalhost.com/in/10`

Notice no :opt and instead 10, as this is a parameter value within the route. It takes all values prefixed with a : as parameters within the req (request) object. In this case, you could check the value of `req.params.opt` and it would be 10 with the above URL.

The app.get defines the HTTP method as a GET, as opposed to a POST/PUT etc.

[More on express routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks that was quite helpful .